# Работа с числами

Tags: java

Нужно создать программу, которая "берет" случайное число (0-10000) и:

1. Выводит на экран количество цифр. Пример `[4867->4]`
2. Первую цифру слева `[6846->6]`
3. Сумму всех чисел `[473->14]`
4. Число в обратном порядке `[5892->2985]`

Проблема в том, что в java строки - это объекты, а не массивы, и я не знаю, как перевести стоку в объект, чтобы далее обращаться к его элементам.

Comment: поконкретнее, если можно

Comment: Во-первых, язык программирования я угадаю с 7 букв.

Во-вторых, что мешает вам создать такую программу? Где трудности?

Comment: Во-первых укажите что это учебное задание.  
Во-вторых, нормально оформите вопрос.  
И в-третьих, какой язык программирования?

Comment: @Sh4dow как мы с Вами одновременно прокомментировали ;)

Comment: Sh4dow, почему с семи, если с шести?!

Comment: @knes, угадывайте)
@metazet, еще и в одном стиле)

Comment: pascal/delphi - 6
basic - 5
c++, что вряд ли, - 3

Кстати, если это задание на программирование чего-то типа тьюринга/поста/брейнфака, то все наезды снимаю, даже с учетом бредово-учительского стиля задания.

Comment: Шит. О яве я, как-то, не подумал. С каких пор?

Comment: javascript - 10 =) Уже отметили, java. Я не шарю, потому ретируюсь)

Comment: Яваскрипт точно не было бы. Его в школах не проходят. А зря, как и питон/пхп/перл и прочие.  
И, кстати, javasc - уже достаточно для определения

Comment: Господа, прекращайте флудить ;)

Answer (score 4):

Вероника, судя по всему, чтобы решить поставленные задачи, вы решили представить сгенерированное число в виде строки, а затем работать с отдельными символами этой строки. Несмотря на то, что такой подход, в принципе, возможен, он неэффективен. Обычно, когда просят решить задачи, подобные вашим, то подразумевают работу исключительно с числами, а не строками. И в самом деле, ваши задачи можно решить, работая непосредственно со сгенерированным числом, не переводя его в строку, массив, или какой-либо другой объект. Чтобы понять как, нужно запомнить два простых правила, которые нам понадобятся. Предположим, мы имеем некоторое число 1234. Тогда:

```
1234 % 10 == 4
1234 / 10 == 123
```

Символ '%' обозначает в Java операцию деления по модулю, то есть, `x % y` возвращает остаток от деления x на y. Символ '/' вам знаком - это деление нацело. Посмотрите еще раз на эти две формулы. Их смысл таков: имея любое число, мы можем получить его правую цифру, просто найдя остаток от деления на 10. А поделив нацело на 10, мы получим число, состоящее из оставшихся цифр. Проделав несколько раз эти операции в цикле, мы можем перебрать все цифры в некотором числе, справа налево, и проделать с ними некоторые полезные вещи, к примеру, просто распечатать:

```
int num = 1234;
while (num != 0) {
    System.out.println(num % 10); // Печатаем крайнюю правую цифру числа `num`
    num = num / 10; // Изменяем переменную `num` таким образом, чтобы она стала равна числу из оставшихся цифр
}
```

Смысл этой программы таков: пока число `num` не равно нулю, мы проделываем следующие вещи: 1. распечатываем крайнюю правую цифру; 2. делаем так, чтобы `num` стал числом, состоящим из оставшихся цифр. Затем повторяем все еще раз: проверяем, не равен ли `num` (уже новый, состоящий из оставшихся чисел) нулю, и проделываем эти две операции повторно. Тело цикла выполнится ровно 4 раза:

```
1 итерация:
  num == 1234
  num % 10 == 4
2 итерация:
  num == 123
  num % 10 == 3
3 итерация:
  num == 12
  num % 10 == 2
4 итерация:
  num == 1
  num % 10 == 1
5 итерация:
  num == 0, что не удовлетворяет условию цикла (n должно быть не равно 0), а значит, цикл завершается
```

Этот код выведет на экран последовательность:

```
4
3
2
1
```

Вместо того, чтобы просто выводить цифры нашего числа, мы могли бы сделать с ними что-то полезное. Например то, что требуют ваши задачки. Начнем с подсчета суммы цифр числа:

```
// Возвращает сумму цифр в числе `num`.
public static int digitSum(int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        sum += num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Затем можно попробовать зеркально отобразить последовательность цифр в числе. Это, пожалуй, самая трудная задачка.

```
// Возвращает число с переставленными обратном порядке цифрами числа `num`.
public static int mirrorNum(int num) {
    int mirror = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        mirror = mirror * 10 + (num % 10);
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return mirror;
}
```

Чтобы понять, как работает этот код, рассмотрим каждую итерацию в отдельности. Предположим, число, которое мы хотим "отзеркалировать", 1234, тогда:

```
1 итерация:
  num == 1234
  mirror == mirror * 10 + (num % 10) == 0 * 10 + 4 == 4
2 итерация:
  num == 123
  mirror == mirror * 10 + (num % 10) == 4 * 10 + 3 == 43
3 итерация:
  num == 12
  mirror == mirror * 10 + (num % 10) == 43 * 10 + 2 == 432
4 итерация:
  num == 1
  mirror == mirror * 10 + (num % 10) == 432 * 10 + 1 == 4321
5 итерация:
  num == 0, что не удовлетворяет условию цикла, завершаем его выполнение
```

На 4-ой итерации переменная `mirror` станет равна 4321 - зеркально отраженному числу 1234, что и требовалось получить.

С рассчетом количества цифр и крайней левой цифры я предлагаю вам разобраться самостоятельно. Полный код программы с решениями всех задачек можно взять [здесь](https://gist.github.com/1208230). Скомпилировать и запустить программу из командной строки можно так:

```
Z:\Dev\1>javac Main.java

Z:\Dev\1>java -Dfile.encoding=CP866 Main
Сгенерировали число: 6165
Количество цифр в этом числе: 4
Первая цифра слева: 6
Сумма цифр в числе: 18
Число с обратным порядком цифр: 5616
```

Comment: о_О это, наверно, самый большой и развернутый ответ на ХэшКоде :)

Comment: Есть еще длиннее: http://hashcode.ru/questions/10254/ :)

Answer (score 3):

"чтобы далее обращаться к его элементам" - вы можете получить символ из заданной позиции в строке методом [String.charAt(i)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)). Обращение строки можно сделать и через [StringBuilder.reverse()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()), если вам это разрешено. Если будете складывать цифры в числе используя вышеприведенный charAt(), не забудьте, что несмотря на то, что вы можете складывать char'ы, их значения после автоприведения к int не равны значениям цифр числа.

**UPD.**
Использовать charAt(), можно, например, так:

```
String exampleStr = String.valueOf(example);
char c = exampleStr.charAt(0); // вернет первую цифру числа
```

Comment: Вывела 10 случайных чисел. Не могли бы вы, @yozh, подробне написать, как использовать метод `String.charAt(i)` в моем примере.

    public class Zikl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 10;                  // печатает 10 случайных чисел от 0 до 100
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int example = (int) (Math.random()*100);
            System.out.print(example + " ");
        }}

Comment: А если обратиться, к примеру, не к первому, а к 3-му элементу? Как это сделать?

Comment: charAt(2)

Answer (score 0):

Если с массивами Вам проще, то для перевода строки в массив символов используйте метод toCharArray()

```
String s = "12345";
char [] ar = s.toCharArray();
int  l = ar.lenght;  // размер полученного массива
```

Для перевода цифры из символьного представления в числовое

```
int ndig = ar[0] - '0';  // перевод первой цифры числа
```